# Do both BeginInvoke and EndInvoke on delegates generate full fences?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

[Threading in C# by Joseph Albahari](http://www.albahari.com/threading/part4.aspx) talks briefly about it, stating:

The following implicitly generate full fences:

- C#'s lock statement (Monitor.Enter/Monitor.Exit)
- All methods on the Interlocked class (we’ll cover these soon)
- Asynchronous callbacks that use the thread pool — these include
  asynchronous delegates, APM callbacks, and Task continuations
- Setting and waiting on a signaling construct
- Anything that relies on signaling, such as starting or waiting on a Task

As "asynchronous delegates" is in the list, I'd assume that at least EndInvoke is fully fenced. But what about BeginInvoke? Unfortunately I couldn't F11 (= debug step) into the BeginInvoke code - is the source available somewhere? Although a link to a definite answer would be even better.

Comment: (BeginInvoke is provided by the runtime itself; there isn't really any source as such)

Comment: You mean they developed those two methods directly in machine code? ;) But honest, it would be nice to know if there's any kind of guarantee in terms of thread safety, independent of whether there's a way to look at MS' sources or not. I could find neither of the words 'barrier', 'fence', 'volatile' in partitions II and IV of the 'latest standards' or the 'working draft' that I downlaoded from [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/aa569283.aspx]

Comment: Not necessarily machine code, C or C++ probably. If you really want to look at it you might download the Mono sourcecode to see how they did it.

Comment: @mrjoltcola Why looking at Mono source when .NET source is available?

Comment: @Tomas Voracek - as you claim it exists, please send a link / description how to get the source code of BeginInvoke and EndInvoke.

Comment: @Eugene http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/16/net-framework-library-source-code-now-available.aspx - System.Windows.Forms is also there

Comment: @Tomas, as you seem to resist reading the specifics, once again. Where exactly is the source of "BeginInvoke"? I cannot find it. And Windows Forms has nothing to do with "BeginInvoke on delegates", which is what I am asking for. I am NOT talking about Control.BeginInvoke.

Answer (score -1):

MSDN says BeginInvoke is threadsafe: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0b1bf3y3.aspx

> there are four methods on a control that are thread safe: Invoke,
>   BeginInvoke, EndInvoke, and CreateGraphics if the handle for the
>   control has already been created

Comment: I believe the question author was not asking about `Control.BeginInvoke`, but the `Delegate`'s `BeginInvoke` and `EndInvoke`.

Comment: Yep, in this case, I'm not interested in Control.BeginInvoke, but Begin/EndInvoke on delegates.

Answer (score -1):

The source code the entire framework is available from Microsoft at the [Reference Source Website](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/netframework.aspx)

Comment: Where exactly is the source code for BeginInvoke and EndInvoke? I'm on .net 3.5SP1, so I looked into the sources for ".NET_3.5_sp1_redist" - they are not in there. Like Marc Gravell said, it is probably in the sources of the runtime itself, not the .net library running on top of it (and that I could download the sources of thanks to your link).